# Снижается репутация без какого-либо уведомления

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Как узнать, куда делась репутация?

Comment: Покажите хоть картинкой, откуда вы решили, что убавляется? )

Comment: В профиль зайди - 5 сообщений удалились - написано же.

Comment: @Qwertiy где вы это видите?)

Comment: Аннулировали все `+2`, которые вы получили за правку этих вопросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё показывается на [странице профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312578/doox911?tab=reputation)

> [image: скриншот]

Удалены эти сообщения:

- [Реализовать функцию через карринг [закрыт]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1006417/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3)
- [Как изменить масштаб pdf файла генерируемого mPDF?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863523/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1-pdf-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-mpdf)
- [PHP/MYSQL: не работает SELECT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997379/php-mysql-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-select)
- [Как написать требуемые поля формы с использованием javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-javascript)
- [не убирается класс transparent + консоль говорите об ошибку в строке tableCell.addEventListener('click', function()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998079/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-transparent-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-tablecell-a)

Comment: У меня просто не стояла галочка — **показать удалённые сообщения**

Comment: А как узнать причину удаления?

Comment: Эм. Ответ вообще не связан с вопросом. Вопрос про "снижение репы". Вернее, сняли за удаление, да, но не объяснили почему)

Comment: P.S. эта инфа видна только модераторам и автору. Не думаю, что эту инфу стоит светить в паблик )

Comment: @doox911, перейти по ссылке и прочитать. Хотя стоп.. Сначала набрать 10К репутации... Всё удалено Духом, первый с причиной RemoveAbandonedClosed, второй - RemoveAbandonedQuestions, оставшиеся - RemoveDeadQuestions.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну в данном случае ничего секретного нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy авторы тех вопросов теперь знают, кто ставил минус их вопросу и могут начать мстить   (¬‿¬)

Comment: @Suvitruf, какой минус вопросу? За минус был бы -1 и он бы добавился, сделав +1 к репутации. А тут по -2, т. е. изначально было +2 - это предлагаемая правка. А её и так видно в истории вопроса.

Comment: @Qwertiy да-да. У меня уже просто кочерышка не соображает в 12 ночи воскресенья. Пора спать, видимо   (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, после удаления вопросов у вас сняли репу, которую ранее дали за правки этих вопросов.

Если глянуть [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> за принятую предложенную вами правку: +2 (всего до +1000 на одного участника)

Насколько я могу судить, вы правили все эти удалённые вопросы. Вот все эти `+2` и аннулировались после удаления оных.